# Choose an specific column of an imported text file

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to import a text file into Python. The first column is date and others are integers. After importing the text file I want to extract each column, name them and plot each variable vs date (the first column). How can I extract columns? And how can I choose the 2nd column onwards? I tried two different methods for importing the file:

```
btcv = np.genfromtxt('example_Feb.388.btcv.txt', dtype=None);
```

and

```
btcv = pd.read_csv('example_Feb.388.btcv.txt', header = None)
```

The text file looks like:

```
"2015-06-17 00:00"  -6.830000   -5.642747   -5.642747   -4.057440   -3.867922   -4.377454
"2015-06-18 00:00"  -6.830000   -5.630413   -5.630413   -4.045107   -3.855588   -4.365120
"2015-06-19 00:00"  -5.245973   -5.627623   -5.627623   -3.967911   -3.836147   -4.309624
"2015-06-20 00:00"  -4.568952   -5.620628   -5.620628   -3.871517   -3.837915   -4.238232
"2015-06-21 00:00"  -4.620864   -5.615302   -5.615302   -3.980928   -4.001598   -4.272657
"2015-06-22 00:00"  -4.673435   -5.622433   -5.622433   -4.025599   -4.071035   -4.285809
```

With 1000 rows and 188 columns.

I tried

```
btcv.date = btcv[:,0]
```

and it did not work! and `btcv[0]` returns the full array.

Thanks.

Comment: The file layout looks like it's using tabs instead of commas. Can you specify the delimiter to be the tab character?

Comment: @ajawad987 Yes, and after defining delimiter it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using pandas you can read it as a csv and set the delimeter to whitespace

```
pd.read_csv('example.csv', delim_whitespace=True, header=None)
```

This will read the file into a pandas dataframe. You can then name your columns. For example

```
df.columns = ['date',  'first', 'second']
```

then you can access each column by name E.g

```
date = df.date
```

make the date the frame index

```
df.index = df.date
```

and then plot the data frame with a plotting tool

Comment: Thanks, Delimiter is tab ('\t'). but how I can extract each column separately?

Comment: Awesome, Now that I defined delimiter I can just use btcv[0] as date and also separate others. Thank you so much.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I've edited it to give a better answer to the overall question